# Initialization of std::vector size in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, initialization, size

Why can't I initialize `std::vector` size in Visual Studio?

```js
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include "Lexer.h" // TokenRule definition

vector<TokenRule> tokenRules(3) = {
    { TokenType::Identifier, regex("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*") },
    { TokenType::Number, regex("[+-]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?") },
    { TokenType::String, regex("\\\"(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\1.)*?\\\"") }
};
```

IntelliSense typecheck:

```
std::vector<TokenRule *> tokenRules(3) = {
                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: Can I initialize size and values at the same time?

Comment: That depends on what values you want to initialize the vector with.  Are they all the same value? If so, vector has a 2-parameter constructor for that purpose (count and value).  Or are the values different?  If so, then use brace-initialization (C++11 and later), or a pair of iterators from an array or other container.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one initialization for any object - you can either do the

```
std::vector<TokenRule *> tokenRules(3);
```

which would call the constructor, declared as `vector(size_type _Count)`, creating a vector with 3 default-initialized elements, OR

```
vector<TokenRule> tokenRules{
{ TokenType::Identifier, regex("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*") },
{ TokenType::Number, regex("[+-]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?(e[+-]?[0-9]+)?") },
{ TokenType::String, regex("\\\"(?:(?=(\\\\?))\\1.)*?\\\"") }   };
```

which would call `vector(initializer_list<value_type> _Ilist)` - completely different constructor. The latter is what you want, since it will use the size of `initializer_list` to determine desired vector size (3 in your case).

Note that `vector<TokenRule*> tokenRules = XXX` is pretty much syntactic sugar for `vector<TokenRule*> tokenRules(XXX)`, and the only reason you can't do `tokenRules = 3` is that `std::vector` explicitly forbids it. So in some way you could say that your code amounts to

```
std::vector<TokenRule *> tokenRules(3){/*initializer list here*/};
```

featuring 2 initializers for 1 object. Hopefully, this would make the source of error a bit clearer.

You could also do

```
std::vector<TokenRule *> tokenRules(3);
tokenRules = {/*initializer list*/};
```

Alhough this is a bit redundant (and error-prone as such), the actual performance loss should be next to 0.